# How to set field attributes in magento module configuration xml?

Tags: xml, magento, configuration, config

I want to use standard magento configuration field types in my module configuration page. It works fine with texts or images. But now I came up with a problem trying to set label or link.

**1) How do you set href attribute for a link field?**

**2) How do you set other html attributes (class, style, rel etc) for any field?**

I wanna achieve this only by using system.xml so I don't need to write my custom models just for displaying some static info.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To add a class, use frontend_class:

```
<fields>
    <field_name translate="label">
        <frontend_class>class_name</frontend_class>
    </field_name>
</fields>
```

You can use jQuery on that class to customise the field.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. Tried it out - class can be added this way. Other attributes (style, href, rel etc) can't. I'm sure this would work but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.